# What the real Time complexity of Fibonacci recursion function

Tags: recursion, fibonacci, mat

I am confused about whether the complexity of the Fibonacci function function is 2^n or the golden ratio raised to power n.

"I have noticed that many websites state that the complexity of this recursion is 2 to the power of n."

Comment: Please include some sources for your claims.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `mat`??

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this pseudocode to calculate

```vb
function F(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n  ' F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1
    return F(n-1) + F(n-2)
```

Let's call  the number of elementary operations (of O(1) complexity) needed to calculate .

Then we have constants  and  such that:

- <sub>0</sub> =
- <sub>1</sub> =
- = <sub>−1</sub> + <sub>−2</sub> +

Here we take addition as a constant time operation, included in .

We can see this sequence:

- <sub>2</sub> = 2 +  = 2(+) −
- <sub>3</sub> = 3 + 2 = 3(+) −
- <sub>4</sub> = 5 + 4 = 5(+) −
- ...
- = <sub>+1</sub>(+) −  = θ(<sub>+1</sub>)

As  = θ(φ), we have that:

= θ(φ<sup>+1</sup>) = θ(φ)

With Big O we cannot get an equivalent expression by changing the *base* of an exponentiation. [Wikipedia on Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties) warns about this:

> On the other hand, exponentials with different bases are not of the same order. For example, 2 and 3 are not of the same order.

And so we cannot say  = θ(2), because φ is not 2, but 1.618...

On the other hand, since in theory big O gives an *upper* bound, we *can* actually say that  = O(2), but it is not a precise bound. More precise is using big Omega so to identify a *tight* bound.

In conclusion we have these truths:

- = θ(φ)
- = O(2)

But:

- ≠ θ(2)

Comment: Any feedback on this answer? Did this take away the confusion?